# Slipstreaming database changes in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a bunch of legacy code without a Model layer separating it from the database.  SQL statements abound.  I would like to normalize tables in the database, yet not have to rewrite all this embedded SQL (eventually I will).  I've tried updatable views in MySQL, but for anything of any complexity, it will perform a full table scan.

Can anyone suggest a clever way to hide database schema changes from clients that heavily rely on those very schemas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no clever way to do it all at once. It's bound to be a difficult, meticulous process. Here are some tips:

- Refactor your application code so that you don't have SQL code littered around the whole codebase. Refactor so that all the literal SQL is consolidated in a few "data access" classes, with sensible APIs. This is something you can do gradually.
- Develop a thorough suite of system tests that you can run against your application so as you change the database schema, you can re-run the tests to ensure you didn't break something. This is also something you can develop gradually.
- Use read-only views where you can. You can't make views for complex  SQL queries as *updatable* views, but at least you can use views for the reading queries. I'm not sure why that would cause a table-scan where the original query did not. Sometimes views cause a *temporary table*, which is also costly.
- In some cases, it's easier to make a view for the new tables. In other cases, it's easier to make a view for the old tables. Keep your options open to do it either way, on a case-by-case basis.
- In your data access classes, you may have to double the database work. For example, saving data changes to the old tables and the new refactored tables as part of the same operation. Once you have tested to make sure all the database queries are using your data access class, you can then take out the code that maintains the legacy tables.
- Eventually, you will have to bite the bullet and make some schema changes that require a "big bang integration". That's the term I've heard for a change that causes a lot of changes across all your code. It's a lot of work to do all the testing necessary to ensure nothing breaks. Sorry, there's no magic to avoid that work. But you can prepare for it with your data access layer and lots of system tests.

This is probably a question that the Stack Overflow community will close as "opinion-based".

Comment: I was going to address these point-by-point. But no matter.  Like I said, common-sense suggestions but very difficult to pull off. 1) is the intention and 2) will definitely be necessary. 5) might (double-bookeeping, via update triggers) might be closest I can get to what I'm looking for.

Comment: I didn't mean to suggest doing the double-entry by triggers. That's not possible in general, because a trigger has access only to columns in its own table. In cases where the refactoring would lead you to store in multiple tables, this won't work. Instead, write your data access class to insert twice to two different table sets.

Comment: And yes, it's difficult to do significant refactoring in the database. Lots of work.